# Is the series based on a game?

Tags: animation, video-game-adaptation, huntik

While watching [Huntik: Seekers and Secrets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntik%3a_Secrets_&_Seekers), something seemed odd how they would receive missions. If the mission involved an uncharted ruin the image they would get would show what it would look like, something you would expect in a video game. Also how their objectives are worded seems like it was meant for a video game.

Also there are the monsters they summon, despite some showing off their special abilities, you don't see how their announced stats have any effect unlike other video game based shows like Yu-Gi-Oh or Bakugan where the stats are explained and how they impact the battle.

So I am wondering if *Huntik: Seekers and Secrets* is actually based on a video game or even a prequel to it (considering how it ended and I have yet to see any episodes that continue after that).

Comment: Wikipedia says its a spin-offs to the Winx Club series. There is no mention of any video game.

Answer (score 2):

Huntik: Seekers and Secrets is part of a media franchise called Winx Club, which includes a television series, books, clothing, video games, product line, DVDs, and theatrical films. Maybe the writers tried to keep the story adaptable to any media, and that's why the story is gaming-like.